# Understanding symbols in Scheme

Tags: scheme, symbols, sicp

I am having a hard time understanding symbols in Scheme. The following confuses me:

```
1 ]=> (symbol? 'x)
; Value: #t    
1 ]=> (symbol? '('x))
; Value: #f
```

I thought I understood why the first one is a symbol, but then why is `'('x))` not? Can someone please explain why?

For what it's worth, I am running MIT/GNU Scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scheme `'...` is a shorthand for `(quote ...)`.

Thus `'x` is shorthand for `(quote x)`.
And `'(1 2 3)` is shorthand `(quote (1 2 3))`.

When a quote expression is evaluated, the quoted values is not evaluated as an expression, but simply returned.

In `(quote x)` what is quoted is the symbol `x`. So `(quote x)` evaluates to the symbol `x`.

In `(quote (1 2 3))` the quoted value is a list. It evaluates to `(1 2 3)`.

In your slightly more complicated example, you have

`'('x)`  which is shorthand for `(quote ((quote x)))`.

This evaluates to the list `((quote x))`. Which in most Schemes are
printed as `('x)`.

Answer (score 1):

`'('x)` is a list, not a symbol.  Symbols in Scheme are alphanumeric, like variables and keywords.  So `'a` is a symbol, and so is `'supercalafragalistic`, but `'(1 2 3)` is a list of numbers.

I'm not sure exactly what's throwing you off, but it's probably the `'`.  `'` can be used to make symbols, but also to make lists, and other things too.  Not everything that starts with `'` is a symbol.

Comment: Well, really they don't need to be alphanumeric.  Scheme has really free naming conventions.. For example `'*foo*` is just as much a valid symbol as `'foo`.

Comment: Yes, it just seemed like a good idea to be specific in this case.